# How do I install a scanner driver for a Brother mfc-7420?

Tags: drivers, brother

I am having difficulty installing driver for my mfc-7420 scanner. I got the printer portion right. But I think I may have got wrong driver downloaded for scanner. Now I think I have right one but won't let me install. Help!

Answer (score 3):

The required package needs to be installed "sane-utils"

```
sudo apt-get install sane-utils
```

Next download the correct version of the Linux Driver from:

[Brother Scanner Drivers](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html#brscan2)

for USB installation follow these instructions [HERE](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1a.html)

Settings for normal users:

```
1. Open "/lib/udev/rules.d/40-libsane.rules" file.
2.Add the following two lines to the end of the device list. (Before the line "# The following rule will disable ..."):

The lines to be added--------------------------- 


# Brother scanners
ATTRS{idVendor}=="04f9", ENV{libsane_matched}="yes"


3. Restart the OS.
```

#### all instructions found [HERE](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1.html)

Comment: The links above appear to be 404 now, but I was able to find all the pieces here (Ubuntu link): https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=mfc7420_all&os=128

Answer (score 0):

I tested the Driver Install Tool (reasonable new 08/19/2021) and it worked fine with both printing and scanning.

Link from Brother Support webpage: https://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us_ot&lang=en&prod=mfc7420_all&os=128